How we can add expense record in QuickBooks Online via API
I am working on an integration with QuickBooks online, I have to create workorder as expense records in quickbooks online, I am exploring the following API for the reference
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/account
but unable to find an endpoint for expense record fetching and creation in quickbooks online.

Solution: We can use the purchase order endpoint for expense record creation.
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/purchaseorder
